# How to use onclick function with window.redirect?

Tags: javascript, onclick, redirect

I have a questionnaire that auto redirects the user to the next page once they've answered all the questions. I also need to use an onclick function to fire some pixels when the user leaves (since I don't have access to the next page's code). Normally, I would simply add the function to the a href that the user clicks to leave, but there is no a href in this case.

Here is the redirect code I'm using:

```
<script>
    window.redirect = () => {
        window.location.href = "NEXT_PAGE_URL"
    }
</script>
```

Below is the pixel code used for the onclick function, fbLeadEvent()

You can see that the pixels for Google Analytics and Snapchat are fired by function pixelEvent() which is inside function fbLeadEvent()

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics*/
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []
function gtag() {
  dataLayer.push(arguments)
}
gtag('js', new Date())
gtag('config', 'UNIVERSAL_ANALYTICS_ID')
gtag('config', 'ADWORDS_ID')
/* Trigger Pixel Code */
function pixelEvent() {
  snaptr('track','VIEW_CONTENT')
  gtag('event', 'generate_lead', {
    'send_to': 'ADWORDS_ID',
    'user_id': 'replace with value'
  })
}
</script>


<script>
  !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s) {
  if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
  n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
  if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
  n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
  t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
  'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
  fbq('init', 'FACEBOOK_ID')
  fbq('track', 'PageView')
  function fbLeadEvent() {
    window._fbq.push('track', 'Lead')
    pixelEvent()
  }
</script>
```

So how does one use an onclick function with an auto redirect?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "this instance"? Instance of what?

Comment: I think he meant in this case by instance.

Comment: Why can you do it within the redirect function? Maybe use `setTimeout` to fire whichever functions you need to and then redirect

Comment: Please tell us the function that is called on `onClick` that fire's up your Facebook Pixel, so that you can call that directly in `window.redirect`

Comment: Yes I updated "instance" to "case" in my original post, as well as added the onclick function used to fire my pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `window.location` without the function for 'redirect'

```
function fbLeadEvent() {
  window._fbq.push('track', 'Lead')
  window.location = "https://www.NEXT_PAGE_DOMAIN.com/page?queryString=1"
}
```

However, you really should be doing redirects from a DNS level, client side redirecting is a pretty big no-no. Also make sure it has the right headers... 301 or 302

Comment: Why client side redirecting is a pretty big no-no?